# WebElement is not clickable

Tags: selenium

I am automating the software by using selenium and there is a web element which is located inside the frame and needs to be clicked.

I tried the following ways.
by using expectedCondtion class.
by using thread.sleep()
by using a simple click() method of selenium.
by using javascriptExecutor.

but it does not work.

is there another way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all you need to [switch](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#frame-java.lang.String-) to the [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) where the element lives, if you don't - Selenium will not be able to find the element like

   ```
   driver.switchTo().frame("your frame name or ID");
   ```
2. Second, you need to ensure that you're using correct [location strategy](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#location-strategies) and make sure that the locator is correct. Pay attention to error messages / logs as it might be the case the click is intercepted by other element (parent, or cookie popup or whatever)
3. Third, consider using [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) class in order to implement [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) as it might be the case the element is being loaded [asynchronously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) and not immediately available

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10); 
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//your/element/xpath/query"))).click();
   ```

References:

- [How to handle iframes using Selenium WebDriver](http://allselenium.info/handling-iframes-using-selenium-webdriver/)
- [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)